# Convert NIFC GeoJSON daily data to KML file using GeoTools

Tags: geojson, kml, geotools

I am not able to convert the daily NIFC GeoJSON data into KML file using GeoTools lib. I am pretty new to GIS data.

Sample GeoJSON data : https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/5da472c6d27b4b67970acc7b5044c862_0.geojson

I have tried the below code so far:

```
URL url = URLs.fileToUrl(new 
 File("C:\\datasets\\5da472c6d27b4b67970acc7b5044c862_0.geojson"));
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("url", url);
DataStore in = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);

if(in == null) {
  throw new IOException("couldn't open datastore from "+url);
}
SimpleFeatureCollection features = in.getFeatureSource(in.getTypeNames()[0]).getFeatures();
Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration());
encoder.setIndenting(true);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
  encoder.encode(features, KML.kml, os);
  String out = os.toString().replaceAll("kml:", "");
  System.out.println(out);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above code `DataStore in = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);` is not able to find dataStore and is always returning null.

Comment: did you make sure your maven file has a dependency to the `gt-geojsonstore` module?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there might be an [issue](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6702) with the current version of the GeoJSONStore handling URLs but your code works if I use the `GeoJSONDataStoreFactory.FILE_PARAM.key` and a file.

The fix will be in the nightly (25.x) build tonight and will make the 24.0, 23.3 releases in the coming weeks.